# Filter subset of a queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have these models:

```
class Committee(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title",max_length=50,null=False)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Meeting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title",max_length=50,null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date",null=False)
    committee = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I want my view to return all committees in which the logged user is in, and only the meetings that has already happened. I'm trying this code:

```
class MeetingsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'meetings/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'committees_list'
    login_required = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Committee.objects.filter(members__id=self.request.user.id,meeting__date__lte=timezone.now())
```

This returns me a queryset excluding the committees which has no meeting before today. What I want is to get all the committees, and the meeting_set to be filtered by the date. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for two different things; the committees the user belongs to, and their past meetings. Is that the case?

Comment: please clarify what you want with `meeting_set to be filtered by the date`. By what date do you want all meetings to be filtered? `date` is not part of Committee.

Comment: `date` is part of the meeting, which is related to the committee. I want the meetings from a comittee filtered by date in the `meeting_set` of the committee. Actually it returns all the related meetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get only specific meetings, use a prefetch. It will link to all related `Committee` objects:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    prefetch = Prefetch('meeting_set', queryset=Meeting.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now()), to_attr='past_meetings')
    return Committee.objects.filter(members__id=self.request.user.id).prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

Then to access the past meetings in the template you use:

```
{% for committee in committee_list %}
    {{ committee.past_meetings }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. It is only missing one  `)` after the `timezone.now()`. Thank you very much!

Comment: The `.all` in the for is not necessary too.

Comment: @William you are welcome! I update the answer based on your comments.